# How to join guilds automatically with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a selfbot with discord.py for a while. I know it's against the ToS and everything. I've come across an issue of getting whoever runs the selfbot to automatically join a specific server. I've been trying different things for several hours and keep getting a 404 error after looking at older methods of accomplishing this.

This is my current code:

```
@self.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready")
  req = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/invite/q2233fN',{'Authorization':token2})
  print("running")
  print(req.status_code)
```

The output is:

ready
running
404

I'm assuming something is wrong with the api link I'm using. Any ideas?

Comment: short answer: you can’t.

Comment: Please show all your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

404 - not found
The Invitelink or the api endpoint isn't correct. maybe you can try to manually join the server within a browser while having devconsole & networkin tab open. This allow you to inspect requests being made when joining and which data is sent etc. you then can implement this logic within your python code.